# why doesn't trim() work with $.each to remove whitespaces in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `.split()` to generate an array from a comma separated string, but I need to get rid of the white space.

```
var a = "one, two".split(",");

a  ==>  ["one", " two"]

a[1].trim() ==> "two"

$.each(a, function(i,v){v.trim()})  ==> ["one", " two"]
```

What am i missing about trimming whitespace from the second string in the array, and is there a better way to trim the white space from a comma separated string?

Comment: thanks for all the input!  Seeing as a lot of highly ranked so users submitted answers just to remove them a few seconds later, I feel less stupid than i did when I originally posted the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are retrieving the value `v.trim()`, but doing nothing with it. Replace this portion:

```
$.each(a, function(i,v){v.trim()})
```

With this:

```
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = a[i].trim();
}
```

And it should work just fine.

Comment: no it shouldn't. `v` is local to the inner function. assigning to it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JacobAbrahams is right.  `$.each(a, function(i,v){v = v.trim()})  ==> ["one", " two"]`

Comment: @JacobAbrahams I modified it. Good catch there

Comment: See below, I added a concise jquery solution in case you're curious.

Comment: building off @ConnerDouglass' suggestion: 
`var b=[];
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    b.push(a[i].trim());
}`

Comment: Giving this answer the credit, although I'll probably go with @elclanrs suggestion to use regex.

Comment: @jahroy My fault. Typed faster than I was thinking

Answer (score 2):

Just split with a regex:

```
var a = "one,   two,  three  ,  four".split(/\s*,\s*/);

console.log(a); //=> ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

If you have spaces at the beginning or the end you can use `trim` first:

```
a = " one,   two,  three  ,  four  ".trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

Answer (score 2):

`trim()` will return a trimmed string but your original won't be modified, so you have to assign to it.

Answer (score 1):

your inner function doesn't actually return a value. As others have mentioned, `trim` returns a copy of the string with leading and trailing whitespace removed. Also, `each` doesn't use the return values of the functions at all, so you can't use it to replace elements. You need

```
$.map(a, function(v){return v.trim();});
```

for this to work. (Assigning to v won't work, since v is just a local variable.)

Comment: Yep.  This is the most concise answer, and thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use jquery's each do it this way:

```
$.each(a,function(i,v){
  a[i] = v.trim();
}
```